# Why is my method not waiting for the promise to resolve before returning?

Tags: arrays, typescript, promise, protractor, resolve

I am attempting to build an array populated with Merchant names, each having an element ID. I check to see if the row has a value first since I don't know how many merchants will be in the list except that there will be fewer than 20. I want to return the array so I can sort it and perform other manipulations for validations.  The promise is not waiting to resolve before returning.

I can see the array building but I want to output the final list `Banamex Merchant,Dashboard Demo,eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant`

As you can see below, the various ways I'm trying to output the final list are returning before the list is even built even though I've built a promise and am calling `.then()` to return the response in my `it()` statement.

### merchants.po.ts

```
export class MerchantsPage {
        buildMerchantListArray(): Promise < string[] > {
            return new Promise < string[] > (resolve => {
                const list: string[] = [];

                for (let i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
                    this.getMerchantName(i)
                        .isPresent()
                        .then((present) => {
                            if (present) {
                                this.getMerchantName(i)
                                    .getText()
                                    .then((text: string) => {
                                        list.unshift(text);
                                        console.log('building list: ' + list)
                                    })
                            }
                        });
                }

                return resolve(list);

            });
        }

        doBuild() {
            this.buildMerchantListArray()
                .then((list: string[]) => {
                    return console.log('doBuild: ' + list);
                });
        }

        /**
         * Get table element for Merchant's Name of row i
         * @param i
         * @returns {ElementFinder}
         */
        getMerchantName(i: number): ElementFinder {
            return element(by.id('Merchant-' + i + '-Name'));
        }
    }
```

### merchants.e2e-spec.ts

```
import {FooterParams} from '../../../../components/footer/footer.params';
import {Footer} from '../../../../components/footer/footer.po';
import {Logo} from '../../../utility/logo/logo.po';
import {LoginParams} from '../../../authentication/login/login.params';
import {LoginPage} from '../../../authentication/login/login.po';
import {AppPage} from '../../../../app.po';
import {Header} from '../../../dashboard/header/header.po';
import {ElementFinder} from 'protractor';
import {MerchantsPage} from './merchants.po';
import {MerchantsParams} from './merchants.params';

describe('Merchants Pages of Dashboard App', () => {
    let app: AppPage;
    let login: LoginPage;
    let navigation: Header;
    let page: MerchantsPage;

    beforeAll(() => {
        navigation = new Header();
        app = new AppPage();
        login = new LoginPage();
        page = new MerchantsPage();
        app.navigateTo('dashboard').then(() => {
            login.checkAuthentication(LoginParams.user, LoginParams.user_pwd);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        Logo.getLogo().click().then(() => {
            navigation.clickAdminDropdown().then(() => {
                navigation.clickMerchants();
                expect(page.getMerchantsHeader().getText()).toContain(MerchantsParams.merchantsHeaderText);
                Footer.getFooter().then((footer: ElementFinder) => {
                    (expect(footer.getText()).toContain(FooterParams.footer));
                });
            });
        });
    });

    it('should verify the Merchants list view is alphabetical by Name', () => {
        Promise.resolve(page.buildMerchantListArray()).then((arr) => {
            console.log('my list: ' + arr);
        });

        page.doBuild();

        page.buildMerchantListArray().then((response) => {
            console.log('response: ' + response);
        });

    });

});
```

### Console Output

```
Jasmine started
my list:
doBuild:
response:
building list: TestMerchant
building list: Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Dashboard Demo,eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Banamex Merchant,Dashboard Demo,eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: TestMerchant
building list: Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Dashboard Demo,eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Banamex Merchant,Dashboard Demo,eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: TestMerchant
building list: Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Dashboard Demo,eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant
building list: Banamex Merchant,Dashboard Demo,eServices Merchant,Germany Merchant,Global Canada Merchant,Michelle's Business,Paytrace Merchant,TestMerchant

  Merchants Pages of Dashboard App
    √ should verify the Merchants list view is alphabetical by Name
```

Comment: Why do you force exiting the promise in 1500 using setTimeout? That's probably why

Comment: I saw that as a suggestion elsewhere. I was getting the same results before I incorporated the setTimeout too.  I have updated my question with the code I tried not using the setTimeout call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is your promises runs away. You didn't wait for them to complete before the returning promise resolves.

Try this:

```
function buildMerchantListArray() {
  const list: string[] = []
  const promises: Promise<void>[] = []
  for (let i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
    promises.push(
      this.getMerchantName(i)
        .isPresent()
        .then((present) => {
          if (present) {
            this.getMerchantName(i)
              .getText()
              .then((text: string) => {
                list.unshift(text);
                console.log('building list: ' + list)
              })
          }
        })
    )
  }
  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => list)
}
```

Comment: Everything within promises.push() is underlined in red with the error: TS2345:Argument of type 'promise.Promise,void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<void>'. Types of property 'then' are incompatible....etc.

Comment: `promise.Promise,void>`??

Comment: You can change `Promise<void>` to `Promise<any>`, but just looking from the code it should be `Promise<void>`. That should fix the error. It's a minor type check.

Comment: Sorry, typo...
TS2345:Argument of type 'promise.Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<void>'. Types of property 'then' are incompatible....etc.

Still seeing the same error.  There's something else fundamentally wrong.  This function is still in an error state.

Comment: Seems like you are using some promise polyfill. Change to `const promises: promise.Promise<void>[]`

Comment: Hallelujah, that did it! Just needed to change the const promises value and your code suggestions worked. Thank you @unional!

Comment: Rejected your change because the question snippet does not indicate you are using a promise polyfill. Using default Promise is the norm nowadays. :)